# Dynamically add elements to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi I'm new to android and was trying to dynamically add content to a `Fragment`.

I've two `Fragments` inside an `Activity`. The first point to the second like this:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_welcome,
                container, false);
        Button searchActivityBtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.SearchActivityBtn);

        searchActivityBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("##SecondActivity", "search btn click");
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.welcome_fragment, new searchAnnouncementsFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();       
            }
        });                     
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

the second `Fragment` `class` is

```
    public static class searchAnnouncementsFragment extends Fragment {

    public searchAnnouncementsFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search,
                container, false);          
        return rootView;
    }

    //public void onStart(){
    // super.onStart();
    // RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.annunciContainer);
    // Log.d("##onstart", "root:" + (root == null));
    //}

}
```

As you can see i tried to do something in `onStart` `method` but I've always a bunch of errors, the `R.id.annunciContainer` is the `id` of the `fragment_search.xml` `layout`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id ="@+id/annunciContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:background="@color/white" >
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to dynamically add elements like other `FrameLayout` to my `Fragment` ( represented by the above `RelativeLayout` ).

Any thought?

Comment: and what are the bunch of errors you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was searching for are `ListView`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the name of the activity, lets say the name as Activity1,

First create a linear layout or frame layout in the Activity1

Second add the following lines of code to your Activity1 for inflating PlaceholderFragment into your layout in Activity1

```
PlaceholderFragment pf = new PlaceholderFragment();
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.annunciContainer, pf,"place_holder");
ft.commit();
```

For inflating searchAnnouncementsFragment replace PlaceholderFragment with searchAnnouncementsFragment.